# How to create a frame-by-frame animation using svg in native android app

Tags: android, animation, svg, frame

- I know android does not support SVG natively.
- I have chosen [androidsvg](https://code.google.com/p/androidsvg/) to dispay svg files. This lib does not support the SVG-buildin-animations, which is okay, because that's not what I need.

I have extended RealiveLayout to add the svg's to the View. This works fine.

```
public class Graphics extends RelativeLayout {
  public Graphics(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
      super(context, attrs);
  }

  public void showConnectedAnimation() {
    //TODO: show animation     
    SVGImageView svgImageView = new SVGImageView(this.getContext());
    svgImageView1.setImageResource(R.raw.shield);
    addView(svgImageView);
  }
}
```

**issue**
My goal is to have 10 tiny svg files to act as a frame-by-frame animation.
I would prefer to use android's native AnimationDrawable but i can't figure out how to bypass the animation-list.xml

**Possible solution**
Is there any way to dynamicly create the animation list for a AnimationDrawable, filled with dynamlicly created ImageView objects using [SVGImageView](https://code.google.com/p/androidsvg/wiki/SVGImageView) from the svg library?

any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use Canvas to draw svg shapes on some kind of SurfaceView?

Comment: I have read the documentation explaining canvas is for graphics that need to be redrawn frequently. (mostly games). In my case i have a static loop. I guess I could code the animation myself using a timer and a small size canvas for just the loop, but that seems like overkill to me.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it, but it looks like you can add frames to an AnimationDrawable using the addFrame() method.

Something like:

```
ImageView imageView = <get from layout XML or create it>

AnimationDrawable anim = new AnimationDrawable();

SVG svg = SVG.getFromResource(this, R.raw.frame1);
anim.addFrame(new PictureDrawable(svg.renderToPicture()), 10);

svg = SVG.getFromResource(this, R.raw.frame2);
anim.addFrame(new PictureDrawable(svg.renderToPicture()), 10);

.. etc..

imageView.setPictureDrawable(anim);
```

Comment: @A M not yet, havent had time.

Answer (score 0):

```
AnimationDrawable anim = new AnimationDrawable();

SVG svg;

svg = SVGParser.getSVGFromResource(getResources(), R.raw.frame1);
anim.addFrame(new PictureDrawable(svg.getPicture()),500);

svg = SVGParser.getSVGFromResource(getResources(), R.raw.strokes);
anim.addFrame(svg.createPictureDrawable(), 500);

svg = SVGParser.getSVGFromResource(getResources(), R.raw.transformations);
anim.addFrame(svg.createPictureDrawable(), 500);

svg = SVGParser.getSVGFromResource(getResources(), R.raw.gradients);
anim.addFrame(svg.createPictureDrawable(), 500);

//so on

imageView.setImageDrawable(anim);
anim.start();
```